# android - Kotlin - how to access a solid color inside a background's custom Button

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, custom-controls

I have a simple Kotlin project, with the following code :

inside an activity screen, I have a list view :

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ordersListView"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        />
```

this listView uses a custom row UI :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white_color">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Name" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_0"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:text="3" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the Button with id = send_0 uses a custom shape, using that code :

filename = v24/blue_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#2E9BCA"
        android:id="@+id/solid_bng"/>

    <stroke
        android:height="1.0dip"
        android:width="1.0dip"
        android:color="#80ee82ee" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

now, I want to change the "solid_bng" color 
when I click on the Button with id = "send_0".

how can I do that ?

not sure if it is needed : I provide also my customAdapter code :
thanks for any help

:o)

Olivier

filename : CustomAdapter.kt

```
package fr.ormaa.o_service


import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import java.util.ArrayList



class CustomAdapter(private val context: Context, private val imageModelArrayList: ArrayList<ImageModel>) : BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int {
        return count
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

        return position
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return imageModelArrayList.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return imageModelArrayList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

        var convertView = convertView
        val holder: ViewHolder


        convertView = convertView

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = ViewHolder()

            val inflater = context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meal_item, null, true)

            holder?.tvname = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView
            holder?.iv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView) as ImageView

            holder?.send0 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.send_0) as Button
            holder?.send1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.send_1) as Button
            holder?.send2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.send_2) as Button
            holder?.send3 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.send_3) as Button


            convertView.tag = holder
        } else {
            // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
            holder = convertView.tag as ViewHolder
        }

        holder?.tvname!!.setText(imageModelArrayList[position].getNames())
        holder?.iv!!.setImageResource(imageModelArrayList[position].getImage_drawables())


        holder?.send0?.setOnTouchListener(zero_clicked)

        return convertView
    }



    private val zero_clicked = View.OnTouchListener { _, _ ->

        Toast.makeText(context,  "zero clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        false
    }
    private val one_clicked = View.OnTouchListener { _, _ ->

        false
    }
    private val two_clicked = View.OnTouchListener { _, _ ->

        false
    }
    private val three_clicked = View.OnTouchListener { _, _ ->
        false
    }




    private inner class ViewHolder {

        var tvname: TextView? = null
        internal var iv: ImageView? = null

        var send0: Button? = null
        var send1: Button? = null
        var send2: Button? = null
        var send3: Button? = null


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an access to your button in this file, you should call the setBackgroundColor() function, to which you can give the target color.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button gives some useful information on how buttons work.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton gives more details about Material Buttons.

Comment: it seem to not working as the backgrounders button is defined by a "complex" component, like the shape. anyway I tried, and it did not work in my case. thanks for trying to help me :o)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a selector to achieve that.

**blue_button.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#2E9BCA" />

    <stroke
        android:height="1.0dip"
        android:width="1.0dip"
        android:color="#80ee82ee" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

**blue_button_pressed.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#00608A" />

    <stroke
        android:height="1.0dip"
        android:width="1.0dip"
        android:color="#80ee82ee" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

and then **blue_button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button" />
</selector>
```

And use this selector as the background for your button.

Comment: selector is working if I want to change color during press. any idea if I want to do something like a switch : I press : the button is orange, I press the button comes back blue... ?

Comment: In that case use a `Switch` with your custom background and add a new items in the selector `selected = "true"`

Comment: Hi, finally, following your idea, I used a CheckBox. 
I added a state_checked in my button selector, 
and defined the checkbox button with a custom one, and checkbox background with a custom one (here I used the same for tests ) 
it works perfectly. thanks !

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:button="@drawable/blue_button_selector"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button_selector"
        />

Comment: I don't close my question for now because I still need help for the other part of my need :

How can I check the checkBox by code ( and change the color then), with the structure of my code ( the checkbox have a button and background customised using shape ) ?

Comment: You need to keep track of the selected/not-selected booleans in a list and toggle then whenever you change the checkbox selection, so that the recycler view doesn't lose the states.